# Is it better to have an event listener that checks many items, or have each item have its own listener?

Tags: javascript, events, canvas

I am working on building a small canvas application (learning exercise) that builds a tree like structure, and one of the requirements is for the various nodes to respond to a mouse over event. I see two approaches on the event implemention;

1. Have a single event listener for mousemove for the canvas, and when it fires it can iterate (recursively) over all the nodes in the tree and determine if the mouse is over a specific node.
2. Have each node register a mousemove listener, and simply check if the event applies to it specifically.

Both would work, but I am not sure if there are best practices that need to be considered. Is having multiple listeners heavier than performing a broad check across many nodes.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, "Event Delegation" is considered better for performance reasons.  It attaches one listener in memory, which watches for your event at the topmost level of where your event can occur.

Not only does this increase performance, but if you add new elements dynamically (like adding a new node), the existing handler will apply to your new element.

Here are a couple of resources about this, one specifically with Canvas in mind (although it's a bit... dense).

General Delegation / Bubbling: 
https://ehsangazar.com/optimizing-javascript-event-listeners-for-performance-e28406ad406c

Canvas Specific: 
http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/canvas/CanvasEventDelegation.html

Comment: Great! I will check these links out, appreciate the guidance here.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, as ever is 'it depends'.

If you had individual listeners, how much similarity would there be? If they are all unique, then individual listeners will be more flexible.

Alternatively, if you had a single overall listener, how much code would you need, in order to cater to the differences between the nodes? If there are no differences, then this is clearly the best option.

Somewhere in the middle you have to make a judgement call, though most people would lean towards the single listener option, as it *should* use less memory.

Comment: I can see the logic here, and each case may have a different approach. I appreciate the questions, as they are good to ask when considering the design. Right now, in this scenario, each event handler performs exactly the same logic, it just highlights itself. I can see this getting more complex as I implement different types of nodes, where the logic of a type of node would be different for the same event, then moving the logic to at least the grouping would be a better approach instead of building a single listener with a lot of logic.

Comment: Next question then is will your new nodes be 'randomly' placed, or will it be the case that Branch-A is of one type, and all of Branch-B of another type? - Quite unlikely, but that then gives you a third option - add a listener to each branch!